# how to get src attribute of <img> tag using ruby watir

Tags: ruby, watir

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>hello</td>
    <td><img src="xyz.png" width="100" height="100"></td>
  </tr>
</table>



tabledata.rows.each do |row|
  row.cells.each do |cell|
    puts cell.text          
  end
end
puts "end"
```

getting output ->

```
hello
end
```

what should i do for output like this ->

```
hello
xyz.png
end
```

without using Nokogiri.

Comment: thanks AJcodez for editing.it looks more clear now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Getting an attribute**

You can get the attribute of an element using the `Element#attribute_value` method. For example,

`element.attribute_value('attribute')`

For many standard attributes, you can also do:

`element.attribute`

**Output cell text or image text**

Assuming that a cell either has text or an image:

1. You can iterate through the cells
2. Check if an image exists
3. Output the image src if it exists
4. Else output the cell text

This would look like:

```
tabledata.rows.each do |row|
  row.cells.each do |cell|
    if cell.image.exists?
      puts cell.image.src    #or cell.image.attribute_value('src')
    else
      puts cell.text
    end    
  end
end
puts "end"
```

Comment: how can i save this image into database in blob form? @justin ko

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by blob form?

Comment: i mean , If the image is located on my html of a web page, how can i    store an image in a BLOBS field with watir and ruby

Comment: i tried this,img=cell.image.src
image = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(img)).body.
and it is working.